# synchronized block on Object.class in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, atomic

**Consider the following code:**

```
synchronized(Object.class){
...
}
```

**What would it do?**

**I'd like to use it for "implementing atomic" in java,**

**I'd expect that this synchronized block will block all other Threads**

(including the main thread) since they all have access to Object,so that it could be used to ensure that only that synchronized block is running at a time and nothing else,

hence it could be used to "implement atomicness".

Anyway I'm not quite shure about that.

**Could any other thread (including main thread) interrupt that synchronized block?**

Comment: `synchronized(...)` will only block other `synchronized(...)` on the same object. So yes, a `synchronized(...)` synchronizing on a different object will not be blocked.

Comment: I tought synchronized blocked all threads with access to that object, so all with access to Object in this case.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My wording was imprecise and ambiguous. `synchronized(X)` will only block other `synchronized(X)`. A `synchronized(Y)` (with `X != Y`) will not be affected.

Comment: so this doesnt work for blocking all other threads?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: how would you achieve that?

Comment: I know of no possibility to enforce your constraint of blocking all other thread to enter `synchronized(...)`-blocks. You can only "soft-enforce" it by using the same object in all `synchronized(...)`-blocks.

Comment: Aww thats nasty news. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since you are synchronizing on object of `Class` type and there is only one such object per classloader then if your JVM uses only one classloader then only one thread per JVM will be able to execute that `synchronized` block

Comment: so that would actually work as intended?